# Dynamic object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to define a data structure using JSON and validate the actual data using structure definition with JSON definition. I'm trying this in c#.

for example:

```
"PlayerScore":{
        "fields":[
            {
                "name":"Runs",
                "type":"short",
                "isRequired":true
            },
            {
                "name":"Wickets",
                "type":"byte",
                "isRequired":false
            }               
        ]
```

Above is the definition of the data structure. Below is the actual data.

```
{
    "Runs": 20,
    "Wickets": 1
},
{
    "Runs": 20
}
```

I want to validate the data type of "Runs" and "Wickets" only if it is a required field.

Comment: Unable to understand what are you trying to say here... Elaborate in simple way and provide your attempts with it and also add what error you are facing while performing an operation

Comment: rather defining a poco class like public class PlayerScore {public int Runs{get;set;} public short Wickets {get;set;} and then receive the data from the API endpoint, I would like to make it as a complete dynamic one

Comment: If you try to achieve this for an actual use case and not just for learning, then you should take a look at [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/learn/getting-started-step-by-step.html).

Comment: @xdtTransform, no I just want them to work in a dynamic way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newtonsoft's Json.NET (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) supports JSON validation versus its schema. Here is the example from their documentation.

**Sample where validation returns true**

```
string schemaJson = @"{
  'description': 'A person',
  'type': 'object',
  'properties':
  {
    'name': {'type':'string'},
    'hobbies': {
      'type': 'array',
      'items': {'type':'string'}
    }
  }
}";

JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': 'James',
  'hobbies': ['.NET', 'Blogging', 'Reading', 'Xbox', 'LOLCATS']
}");

bool valid = person.IsValid(schema);
// true
```

**Sample where validation returns false**

```
JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

JObject person = JObject.Parse(@"{
  'name': null,
  'hobbies': ['Invalid content', 0.123456789]
}");

IList<string> messages;
bool valid = person.IsValid(schema, out messages);
// false
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Null. Line 2, position 21.
// Invalid type. Expected String but got Float. Line 3, position 51.
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonSchema.htm

Answer (score 1):

Didn't quite get you but if you are trying to validate a json against a Json Schema. This post might be what u need. [Json Schema Validation](https://davidwalsh.name/json-validation)

Not sure why u wanna go that route though. Would it suffice for you to make a C# model and validate the json against it using data annodations? (assuming its an api) Learn about them here [Data Annotations](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Basic-Introduction-to-Data-244734a4)

Comment: thanks @PrajwoCE, what I'm trying to do is creating an API which will receive json in different structures and validate them according to the structure and store all of them in the json format in the same table. Example: if I receive a data like {"ScoreType":1,"Score":{
    "Runs": 20,
    "Wickets": 1
},
{
    "Runs": 20
}} then I will check the definition for ScoreType 1 from the table and validate the received data which is "Score":{"Runs":20...etc the store it in a table

Comment: Why would you want to parse the json object one line/value at a time when you can just validate it against a schema and break it up the way you like to store them? If you make the schema correctly it will do all the validation for you, then you can just break the json and store all of them at once rather than storing them one by one which is more database resource intensive.

Comment: Just now I know there is something available like json schema. So I will use that. Thanks for your reply

Comment: Glad to help. I had exactly the same problem when I was working with XML a while back :)